# Any audio (not music) and video organizer?

Tags: software-recommendation, media, organizer

I have video and audio files where i am playing different instruments in different keys and beats. I would like to have a software where i can 'label' the different files with different categories, so then i can search easily, for example, 'didgeridoo videos in 7 beats'.

So, basically, something like calibre or shotwell but for audio and video (not music).

Answer (score 1):

OK, someone pointed me to [digiKam](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/digikam), which you can configure to accept any audio type.